# US Senate/Congress Contact Info API

Tags: united-states, congress, senate

Is there an API to get the email addresses or other contact info of US senators and representatives by postal code? Or, is there some way of getting the email addresses of all US senators and representatives linked to postal codes (perhaps in JSON of CSV format)?

If this does not exist, where is a good full list of senators and representatives in the States, along with email addresses on the same page?

Also, which states' representatives have publicly disclosed email addresses? Are there any APIs for those as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can find what you're looking for on a website called [Contacting the Congress](http://www.contactingthecongress.org/).  I just searched Google for "[congressman email address](https://www.google.com/search?q=congressman+email+address)" and it was the first link.  They have downloads of their data available as well.